# Распарсить неправильный ответ от сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне приходят с сервера неправильные данные:

```
response_data = "Lastend{'Name': 'Lastend', 'vs': 'obj', 'enemy': 'treid'}5treid{'Name': 'treid', 'vs': 'obj', 'enemy': 'Lastend'}"
```

Я хочу превратить это в dict. Начал городить...

```
response_data = response_data.replace('{', '\':{')
response_data = response_data.replace('}', '},\'')
response_data = '\''+response_data
response_data = response_data[:-2]
response_data = response_data + '}'
response_data = '{' + response_data
print(response_data)
print('------------')
response_data = ast.literal_eval(response_data)
print(type(response_data))
```

Есть ли более изящные решения чтобы сделать это?

Comment: почему такие ответы приходят? почему не обычный json?

Comment: @handowl 
```
prepare_send_to_str = ''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in send_to_clients.items())
                        client.socket.sendall(bytes(prepare_send_to_str, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: @handowl сокет так возвращает.

Comment: если есть возможность поменять формат отправки данных, лучше поменять его, а парсить json (или похожим чем-то)